# Errors and duplicates

Tags: google-apps-script

The following google script is timing out and also seems to be downloading the same attachments multiple times, leading to a serious organization and space issue. Any advice or edits would be very appreciated.

```
var fileTypesToExtract = ['csv', 'xlsm', 'xlsx', 'xls', 'pdf'];

var folderName = 'Audit Grab to Sort';

var labelName = '@indrive';



function GmailToDrive(){

  var query = '';
 
  for(var i in fileTypesToExtract){
    query += (query === '' ?('filename:'+fileTypesToExtract[i]) : (' OR filename:'+fileTypesToExtract[i]));
  }
  query = 'in:inbox has:nouserlabels ' + query;

  var threads = GmailApp.search(query);
  var label = getGmailLabel_(labelName);
  var parentFolder;
  if(threads.length > 0){
    parentFolder = getFolder_(folderName);
  }
  var root = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  for(var i in threads){
    var mesgs = threads[i].getMessages();
    for(var j in mesgs){
      //get attachments
      var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
      for(var k in attachments){
        var attachment = attachments[k];

        var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
        var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
        parentFolder.addFile(file);
        root.removeFile(file);
      }
    }
    threads[i].addLabel(label);
  }
}

function getFolder_(folderName){
  var folder;
  var fi = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  if(fi.hasNext()){
    folder = fi.next();
  }
  else{
    folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
  }
  return folder;
}


function getDateNDaysBack_(n){
  n = parseInt(1);
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'yyyy/MM/dd');
}

function getGmailLabel_(name){
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(name);
  if(!label){
    label = GmailApp.createLabel(name);
  }
  return label;
}


function checkIfDefinedType_(attachment){
  var fileName = attachment.getName();
  var temp = fileName.split('.');
  var fileExtension = temp[temp.length-1].toLowerCase();
  if(fileTypesToExtract.indexOf(fileExtension) !== -1) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

All I am trying to do is download attachments and store them in google drive preferably on a workspace shared drive path, but I will settle for my drive folder if that is the easiest method

Answer (score 0):

> [...] and also seems to be downloading the same attachments multiple
> times

Try first get the names of the files in your destination, then, in your code - (the part you create the files) *check if there is a file with that same name*.

This would avoid duplicates and the issues you mentioned.

***Code sample - untested, but, I hope you get the idea***:

```
// Outside of your functions, create this variable where 
// you store in this variable ONLY the file names: 
var all_my_drive_file_names = [];

// Inside your "GmailToDrive" function: 
//get attachments
var attachments = mesgs[j].getAttachments();
for(var k in attachments){
  var attachment = attachments[k];
  
  // You need to get the file name of the `attachmentBlob` - BEFORE creating the file with `DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);`: 
  var file_name_tmp = attachment.getFileName();
  
  // Check if the file exists on the `all_my_drive_file_names` variable: 
  // if does not exists, you can create the file in the destination
  if (all_my_drive_file_names.indexOf(file_name_tmp) == -1) {
      // These are the lines it creates a file in the destination: 
      var attachmentBlob = attachment.copyBlob();
      var file = DriveApp.createFile(attachmentBlob);
      parentFolder.addFile(file);
      root.removeFile(file);
      
      // Add the name of the created file - in case you find duplicates in the next batch of results. 
      all_my_drive_file_names.push(file_name_tmp);
  }
}
```